# PHP / MYSQL returns array how to do a foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Ok, it seems this would not be so hard, but for some reason it is not liking me today.

so basically the array returns like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => this test [content] => this is a test [releasedate] => 2011-07-23 16:19:59 [publish] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => 'title2' [content] => 'This is story 2'. [releasedate] => 2011-07-23 15:34:25 [publish] => 1 ) )
```

however it seems not to show when I do the following

```
foreach( $res as $story){
    print $story->title;
}
```

Comment: Associated array is not an object class in php, you can't use -> .only if you have an array of objects you can use ->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an associative array, so do `print $story['title']`

Comment: Thank you, that works great, but how do I only allow it to show 1 of the story["title"] I thought by $story[0]["title"] but that does not seem to work, is there an $i thing I need to do?

Comment: `$res[0]['title']` instead of `$story[0]['title']`

Comment: sadly that just prints the same title out twice

Comment: basiclly I want to be able to tell the server what to do with each title, (I am making a news site)

Comment: for that you have not to print it out in `foreach` loop, just do `print $res[0]['title']` without array iteration